# GDB With a coredump file in linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging, terminal, gdb

I just got a core-dump file in linux with

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

how can I attach gdb with it

I need to give command line arguments with it.

sample executation:

```
./my_prog arg
```

Help me to get into gdb

Cheers!!

Comment: I answered but downvoted the question since it is in the GDB documentation which has a nice tutorial. Asking on StackOverflow such basic questions take you more time than reading the start of the documentation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your core file is `core` just run

```
gdb ./my_prog core
```

to do some post-mortem analysis with the `core`.

If you want to use `gdb` without your core, consider

```
gdb --args ./my_prog arg
```

or else run just `gdb ./my_prog` then issue the `set args` command to `gdb`.

If your process is still running as pid 1234, you could with `gdb ./my_prog 1234` attach the gdb to the running process.

You really should **read the [gdb documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html)**.