# Investigating why an installed binary hangs

Tags: linux

I installed a package on my linux machine. When I run the installed binary, it hangs:

```
$installedBinary --help
```

is supposed to return a list of command line options. Instead, the program hangs and doesn't respond. It closes when I run control+c.

How can I investigate this problem?

Comment: What is that package and where did you got it from? On which distribution

Comment: Your binary doesn't hang Linux. It hangs. No need to repeat tags in the title.

Comment: @n.m. "binary" has long been a misnomer for "executable". `/dev/random` is also binary.

Comment: It is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain what *actual* package you have installed, and you could get a lot more help.

Comment: No, the answer can only be package specific, if you want a reliable one. Those that you've got won't help you much. BTW, some rare (even benign) software are very difficult to `strace` reliably (e.g. setuid programs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should strace be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/174942/608639), [How to debug using gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2069367/608639), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with `strace -ffo traces ./installedBinary --help`. And then inspect `traces.*` log files, in particular the last lines where it may show what it is blocked on. See [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

You can also do that from [htop](https://hisham.hm/htop/). Locate the blocked thread and press `s` for `strace` and `l` for `lsof`.

Comment: Great. Notice that `strace` is not for debugging *packaged* binaries, but to understand the system calls done by running *any* executables (including those that are not packaged)

Comment: Also, `strace` don't work well on setuid executables

Answer (score 0):

[Maxim Egorushkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52412291/841108) is a good one. But on Linux, most programs have some documentation (often, at least a `man` page, see [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) & [man(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man.7.html)), and most programs are free software. And the documentation should tell a lot more than `--help` does (the output of `--help` is a short *summary* of the documentation; for example [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) explains a *lot* more than `sed --help`). Maybe the behavior of your program is explained in the documentation (e.g. depends upon some environment variable).

So you should also read the documentation of your `installedBinary` and you probably could get its source code, study and recompile it. If you have the source code and have built it, you usually could compile it with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information (e.g. adding `-g` to some `CFLAGS` in a `Makefile`...) and [run it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984938/841108) under `gdb`

Notice that even on Linux you might have [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) (e.g. for Debian or Ubuntu you might have found a `.deb` source which is used to publish malware; this is unlikely, but not impossible). Trusting a binary package provider is a social issue, not a technical one. Your `installedBinary` might (in principle) be bad enough to put you in trouble. But it is probably some [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable).

Perhaps your `installedBinary` is *always* waiting for some input from its stdin (such a behavior might be unusual but is not forbidden) or from some other source. Then you might try `installedBinary < /dev/null` and even `installedBinary --help < /dev/null`

Comment: I'm curious what you expect to find in the documentation that would be helpful in this investigation. Or are you just suggesting using the documentation instead of using the `--help` option?

Comment: I'm not sure "your command isn't doing anything? it might be malware!" is accurate or useful advice

Comment: We don't *know* the source of the package. Some people might setup e.g. a `.deb` source somewhere (for Debian or Ubuntu) and publish malicious software thru that. It is unlikely, but not impossible. And *trusting* a `.deb` package provider is a social issue, not a technical one