# Debug linux crash dump on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, visual-studio-debugging, crash-dumps

I have got a crash dump of a C++ application from Linux platform. How can I use that on Windows to look at the state of the program (call stack, variable values, thread info, etc.)?

Can I use Visual Studio/VSCode?

Comment: You need to use the tool-chain tools that are: built for or are meant to work with the dump and compiled application.  You don't give enough information in the question to allow any further help.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Maybe [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736235/how-do-you-debug-a-linux-core-dump-using-vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736235/how-do-you-debug-a-linux-core-dump-using-vscode) helps.

Comment: I could not find a proper way to debug linux core dump on Windows. So, I instead set up a linux dev environment and debug(gdb) the core dump there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GDB on Windows for that, if it was compiled with support for Linux targets. But you still need the binaries and symbols.

(Sorry, I don't know if VSCode comes with such a GDB)

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can't debug a Linux core dump just with Visual Studio running on Windows. But you can remote connect the Visual Studio debugger to a Linux machine following these [instructions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/debug-c-code-on-linux-from-visual-studio).